# sam local invoke timeout on newly created project (created via sam init)

Tags: node.js, linux, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, sam

I create a new project via `sam init` and I select the options:

```
1 - AWS Quick Start Templates
1 - nodejs14.x
8 - Quick Start: Web Backend
```

Then from inside the project root, I run `sam local invoke -e ./events/event-get-all-items.json getAllItemsFunction`, which returns:

```
Invoking src/handlers/get-all-items.getAllItemsHandler (nodejs14.x)
Skip pulling image and use local one: public.ecr.aws/sam/emulation-nodejs14.x:rapid-1.32.0.

Mounting /home/rob/code/sam-app-2/.aws-sam/build/getAllItemsFunction as /var/task:ro,delegated inside runtime container
Function 'getAllItemsFunction' timed out after 100 seconds
No response from invoke container for getAllItemsFunction
```

Any idea what could be going on or how to debug this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Any chance the image/lambda make a call to a database someplace? and does the container running the lambda have the right connection string and/or access? To me sounds like your function is getting called and then function is trying to reach something that it can't reach.

As far as debugging - lots of console.log() statements to narrow down how far your code is getting before it runs into trouble.